# mod_rewrite redirect everything except special URLs and files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the following:

1. everything to new domain to start page:
   server1.com, server1.com/start, server1.com/foo.html ... to server2.com/start
2. except special URLs which should redirect to special URL at server 2:
   server1.com/contact (with and without .html) to server2.com/contact
3. except special files which should stay on server1 (no redirect at all):
   server1.com/help.pdf stays at server1.com/help.pdf

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule contact* http://server2.com/contact [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/help.pdf$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://server2.com/start [L,R=301]
```

1 and 2 seem to work but 3 (special files) are also forwarded. Any idea how to fix this and can it be optimized?

Thanks!

Comment: The rule 3 is failing, probably because of your browser cache. Clear your browser's cache and try to visit `/help.pdf` again.

Comment: Allright that did the trick, thanks!